# Java Keytool command in Java 8.0_40 has no -file option?

Tags: java, keytool

I am running keytool in Java 1.8.0_45 and it accepts a -file option for the cert file I want to import.  But Java 1.8.0_40 does not accept the -file parameter.

The 45 is a JDK and the 40 is a JRE.  Is this the problem?  Does keytool work differently on the two versions?

Comment: Don't know about 1.8.0_40. I have a 1.8.0_51 installed and the `keytool.exe -importcert -help` command lists the `-file` option.

Comment: The crazy thing is that v45 shows proper  help, but v40 does not.  Something must be messed up with it.  Are you pointing to a JRE or a JDK, Andreas?

Comment: That was the 64-bit JRE.

Comment: ok, I upgraded to java 8.60 and  all is well. I'm going to attribute the 40 strangeness to a quantum vacuum fluctuation and move on with my life. Thanks!

Comment: If you think this will help others, answer your own question and accept the answer. Otherwise just delete this question.